# Porque docker-compose funciona pero el "docker run" no funciona

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, celery

Tengo el siguiente archivo local.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  celery-worker-default:
    image: weapp_app:latest
    container_name: weapp_celery-worker-default
    command: celery worker -A WeApp -Q default -n default --loglevel=INFO
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/python/current/app/
```

y cuando ejecuto

```
docker-compose -f local.yml up celery-worker-default
```

funciona correctamente, ahora bien si intento ejecutarlo con docker de la siguiente forma

```
docker run -v "$(pwd):/opt/python/current/app/" -w /opt/python/current/app --env-file .env --rm -i -t weapp_app celery worker -A WeApp -Q default -n default --loglevel=INFO
```

me envia el siguiente error

```
Error: 
Unable to load celery application.
The module "WeApp was not found.
```

También intente cambiando el $(pwd) por el path completo y obtengo el mismo error.

Comment: Hola, ¿ya revisaste que *weapp_app:latest* y *weapp_app* sea la misma imagen?
Un truco para *debuggear* esto es correr una consola en lugar de tu comando para ver qué hay adentro. Por ejemplo, si tu imagen tiene bash sería: `docker run -v "$(pwd):/opt/python/current/app/" -w /opt/python/current/app --env-file .env --rm -i -t bash
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muchas gracias por leer la pregunta y por las ideas que me han entregado.

Finalmente el problema era el archivo de las variables de ambiente (en este caso .env)

Vale destacar que el archivo de variables de ambientes para docker-compose acepta la declaración de las variables de la siguiente forma

```
VAR="VALOR"
```

No así para el comando docker las variables de ambientes se deben declarar de la siguiente forma:

```
VAR=VALOR
```

El valor de la variable debe ir sin comillas.

Nuevamente muchas gracias a todos los que leyeron mi publicación.